# Change Power Apps Combo Box single selected value to multiple selection

Tags: forms, combobox, powerapps, sharepoint-list, multipleselection

I have a SharePoint Online List named "Employee Task List" and inside this, I added different columns including the Choice field (Which is a single selection). Also, I created a Power Apps edit form and changed the default mode to "New" and I successfully added a new record to the SharePoint list.

Now, I am required to select multiple selections in combo box control, for that, I already changed the SharePoint choice field to allow multiple selections. However,[image] I am facing an error on the choice field Datacard default property.

Please suggest any solution!

Comment: First refresh the data connection - go to Data on the left, select `...` on the list you've updated and select `Refresh`. Then go to your Form and select `Edit Fields`, and remove Status. Then add it again.

Answer (score 0):

As proposed by Samir in his comment, make sure you refresh the data source first, so Power Apps knows that the field now allows multiple selection. You probably also did that, since 'ThisItem.Status' now has Table data type.

However, the Table datatype is incompatible with the 'Default' property. Instead of 'Default' (that accepts a single record) you will have to configure the 'DefaultSelectedItems' property. The 'Default' property will have to be empty.